# How to feed back HTML table data into the Form to edit it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html-table

I am trying to make a form, that should be a pop up modal, that when submitted the data is stored in a dynamic HTML table, and each row of the data will have a "edit" button in the last column that when clicked fed the data back into the form and can be submitted.

Till now I have completed making a dynamic html table from the form. I cannot fed back the table data into the form. Please help...

My Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .modal-dialog {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 200px;
    }

    #popTab td,
    #popTab th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #popTab tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #popTab tr:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #popTab th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }

    #popTab {
        position: absolute;
        top: 500px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 80%
    }
</style>

<title>Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button id="showModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Click Here</button>
            <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" id="popup" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-tile">Population Form</h4>
                            <button class="close" id="closeModal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                                    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Select country</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="city">City</label>
                                    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">Select city</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="population">Population</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" type=text name="population" id="population" placeholder="Enter Population" maxlength=8 onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save">Save</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="hideModal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <table border="1" id="popTab">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sl. No.</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Population</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showModal').click(function () {
            $('#popup').modal('show');
        });

        $('#hideModal').click(function () {
            $('#popup').modal('hide');
        });

        $('#closeModal').click(function () {
            $('#popup').modal('hide');
        });

        var countryOptions;
        var cityOptions;
        $.getJSON('Country.json', function (result) {
            countryOptions = '<option value="">Select country</option>';
            $.each(result, function () {
                var name = $(this).attr("country_name");
                countryOptions += '<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>';
            });
            $('#country').html(countryOptions);
        });

        $("#country").change(function () {
            cityOptions = '<option value="">Select city</option>';
            if ($(this).val() == "United Kingdom") {
                $.getJSON('city_uk.json', function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        var name = $(this).attr("city_name");
                        cityOptions += "<option value='" + name + "'>" + name +
                            "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#city').html(cityOptions);
                });
            } else if ($(this).val() == "New Zealand") {
                $.getJSON('city_nz.json', function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        var name = $(this).attr("city_name");
                        cityOptions += "<option value='" + name + "'>" + name +
                            "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#city').html(cityOptions);
                });
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Canada") {
                $.getJSON('city_canada.json', function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        var name = $(this).attr("city_name");
                        cityOptions += "<option value='" + name + "'>" + name +
                            "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#city').html(cityOptions);
                });
            } else if ($(this).val() == "Australia") {
                $.getJSON('city_aus.json', function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        var name = $(this).attr("city_name");
                        cityOptions += "<option value='" + name + "'>" + name +
                            "</option>";
                    });
                    $('#city').html(cityOptions);
                });
            }
        });
        var sKey = 0;
        $("#save").click(function () {
            var country = $("#country").val();
            var city = $("#city").val();
            var population = $("#population").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td>" + (sKey + 1) + "</td><td>" + country + "</td><td>" + city +
                "</td><td>" + population +
                "</td><td><button type='button' class='hit'>Edit</button>"
            "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
            $("form").trigger("reset");
            $('#popup').modal('hide');
            sKey++;
        });


    });

    $(".hit").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        alert(value);
    });

    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And why this function is now working? On button press in the html table, this should fetch the first cell of the respective row. Please help...

```
$(".hit").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
        alert(value);
    });
```

The json datas:- 
Country.json

```
[{"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada"},{"country_code":"UK","country_name":"United Kingdom"},{"country_code":"AU","country_name":"Australia"},{"country_code":"NZ","country_name":"New Zealand"}]
```

city_uk.json

```
[{"city_code":"AR","city_name":"Armagh"},{"city_code":"BR","city_name":"Bristol"},{"city_code":"CM","city_name":"Cambridge"},{"city_code":"GL","city_name":"Glasgow"},{"city_code":"HR","city_name":"Hereford"},{"city_code":"LV","city_name":"Liverpool"},{"city_code":"MN","city_name":"Manchester"},{"city_code":"NW","city_name":"Newcastle upon Tyne"}]
```

city_nz.json

```
[{"city_code":"AU","city_name":"Auckland"},{"city_code":"CH","city_name":"Christchurch"},{"city_code":"HM","city_name":"Hamilton"},{"city_code":"TA","city_name":"Tauranga"},{"city_code":"NH","city_name":"Napier-Hastings"},{"city_code":"NE","city_name":"Nelson"},{"city_code":"RO","city_name":"Rotorua"},{"city_code":"WL","city_name":"Wellington"}]
```

city_canada.json

```
[{"city_code":"CP","city_name":"Capitals"},{"city_code":"AL","city_name":"Alberta"},{"city_code":"BC","city_name":"British Columbia"},{"city_code":"MN","city_name":"Manitoba"},{"city_code":"NB","city_name":"New Brunswick"},{"city_code":"NL","city_name":"Newfoundland and Labrador"},{"city_code":"NT","city_name":"Northwest Territories"},{"city_code":"NS","city_name":"Nova Scotia"}]
```

city_aus.json

```
[{"city_code":"AL","city_name":"Albury"},{"city_code":"BT","city_name":"Bathurst"},{"city_code":"OR","city_name":"Orange"},{"city_code":"PR","city_name":"Penrith"},{"city_code":"SY","city_name":"Sydney"},{"city_code":"QB","city_name":"Queanbeyan"},{"city_code":"WA","city_name":"Wagga Wagga"},{"city_code":"NO","city_name":"Wollongong"}]
```

Comment: Put the core source object onto the row using the `$sel.data()`, then you just have to get it back after you handle the event. Try not to actually parse it from the html, if you have the actual data. Better would be to link it to a central data store held in memory (e.g. `getStoreItem($(this).data('ref'))`).

Comment: Here's a rudimentary example of what I mean, in the handlers if operations are enacted, you could send the affected (jsonified) row or the whole `store`: https://jsfiddle.net/7n2y22vy/

Answer (score 1):

You don't get anything because this button in a table is created dynamically, thus, no even is attached on document load. A simple fix is to attach to document and pass element's class name as a second argument like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.hit', function () {
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    alert(value);
});
```